# Q: Alexa Skill. Can an alexa skill bind with multiple lambda functions?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way for an alexa skill to bind to multiple lambda functions?

If the answer is yes, how can the user who downloads the skill configure an ID or something to link the skill to one of the functions?

Any comment is welcomed.

Comment: No, you can only bind to one endpoint/lambda per region. Read my answer for your other question on this subject. I showed you the recommended way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: No.
Possibly the solution is here, but it is not clear to me yet.

https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/questions/242312/how-can-a-single-skill-be-linked-for-multiple-obje.html